# What is WPCups.exe?

Tags: windows, sdk, documentation, executable, malware

I downloaded Microsoft SDK and Visual Studio 2015 on Windows 10 and a shortcut to file WPCups.exe showed up on my desktop. It's located in C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\TShell\TShell.

Some searching has turned up that it might be related to IP phones:

> This is a CMD line utility to test and send ip over usb connectivity. Its included with the the WDK. It will connect to IPoverUSB.exe and will  use RPC to talk to a Windows phone. It will drop a log file in your my documents folder that you may see also btw.

But it still seems odd to me, partially that it would install a shortcut onto my desktop. VirusTotal says it's clean, and IDA's disassembly looks like it's doing what the responder I quoted above says it should do, but I can't find any windows documentation, let alone a hash value.

In another forum someone mentioned that WPCups.exe is normally installed with Microsoft SDK, but I can't find any documentation confirming that.

It calls:

> ADVAPI32.dll, KERNEL32.dll, WSOCK32.dll, WS2_32.dll, msvcrt.dll, IPHLPAPI.DLL, RPCRT4.dll.

Which seems reasonable.

I ran it on malwr.com but the analysis failed, that package "modules.packages.exe" start function raised an error...I suppose because of unmet dependancies? But the program looks like it should still end gracefully even without IPoverUSB.exe present.

Is anybody familiar with this file?

Update:
Because finding Windows documentation is apparently the most immediate path to madness:
From How Linux Works by Brian Ward

> The standard printing system in Linux is CUPS ([Linux CUPS](http://www.cups.org/)), which is the same system used on Mac OS X. The CUPS server daemon is
>   called cupsd, and you can use the lpr command as a simple client to
>   send files to the daemon. One significant feature of CUPS is that it
>   implements *Internet Print Protocol (IPP)*, a system that allows for
>   HTTP-like transactions amont clients and servers on TCP port 631. In
>   fact, if you have CUPS running on your system, you can probablt
>   connect to *http://localhost:631/* to see you current configuration
>   and check on any printer jobs. Most network printers and print servers
>   support IPP, as does Windows, which can make setting up remote
>   printers a relatively simple task.
>
> You probably won't be able to administer the system from the web
>   interface, because the default setup isn't very secure. Instead, your
>   distribution likely has a graphical settings interface to add and
>   modify printers. These tools manipulate the configuration files,
>   normally found in */etc/cups*. It's usually best to let these tools do
>   the work for you, because configuration can be complicated. And even
>   if you do run into a problem and need to configure manually, it's
>   usually best to create a printer using the graphical tools so that you
>   have somewhere to start.
>
> Many printers, including nearly all low-end models, do not understand
>   PostScript or PDF. In order for Linux to support one of these
>   printers, it must convert documents to a format specific to the
>   printer. CUPS sends the document to a Raster Image Processor (RIP) to
>   produce a bitmap. The RIP almost always uses the Ghostscript (gs)
>   program to do most of the real work, but it's somewhat complicated
>   because the bitmap must fit the format of the printer. Therefore, the
>   printer drivers that CUPS uses consult the PostScript Printer
>   Definition (PPD) file for the specific printer to figure out settings
>   such as resolution and paper sizes.

So, point Linux?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, that has nothing to do with the Printing Deamon for Linux.
WPCups belongs to the TShell Powershell Module with is Part of the Development Toolskit for Apps which will be installed with the WDK.